# Identify the script that causes "Refused to execute a script because its hash, its nonce, or 'unsafe-inline' .... f the Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, security

I have CSP configured to block all inline styling and script tags. But I have a html file where there are multiple script tags import.

```
<script src="lib/js/demo1.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/demo2.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/demo3.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/demo4.js"></script>
```

I just see the error in the browser and it does not even tell me which script is causing the issue :

**Refused to execute a script because its hash, its nonce, or 'unsafe-inline' appears in neither the script-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy.**

There are around 15-20 such imports and all I want to do is find the script tag that is causing the issue. Any pointers in that direction will be appreciated.

Comment: "I have CSP configured to block all inline styling *and script tags*". Aren't that script tags you show?

Comment: All inline scripts and css are basically blocked from rendering. Only an external file with the JS/CSS logic can be imported to be used.